# Android drawBitmap() and/or compress() only writes part of image

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, export, png

I'm trying to export a bitmap to a PNG file, but whenever I open the PNG file, it only has the first few lines rendered. I've simplified my code to simply draw the color cyan to the bitmap, yet, when exporting, it only draws about the top 1/8th or 1/4th of the image.

i.e., My canvasWidth and canvasHeight are 2560x1600, the size of the Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 Ed, and only the top 349 or so lines of pixels render the cyan, while the rest is blank.

```
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);

    FileOutputStream fs = null;
    try
    {
        fs = new FileOutputStream(f);

        if (!bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fs))
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Compression failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            errorCode = ERR_STREAM_CORRUPTED;
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        errorCode = ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        errorCode = ERR_IO_EXCEPTION;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.flush();
                fs.close();
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            errorCode = ERR_IO_EXCEPTION;
        }
    }
```

Do I have a problem with the bitmap not being fully written to memory by the time I'm compressing and writing to the file stream? I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: can you try with a smaller width and height and see if it does make any difference?

Comment: I've tried 1280x720, and only the first 580 or so lines filled in. I've tried 640x480, and the full image is filled in. 1280x720 is somewhat a required output size for me.

Comment: More updates on this. After rebooting my device, I'm able to write out a full 1280x720 PNG image the first time. If I kill my app and restart it and try to re-export, it only exports half the image. If it's a memory issue, I'd rather have this warn me that I'm out of memory or something, but otherwise, how can I tell if I'm running out of RAM and/or how can I manage my bitmap memory better?

Comment: Rect rect = new Rect(0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, dest, paint);

Coult try this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. bmp is my destination bitmap, but your example is using it as a source bitmap. Anyway, I've tried your above code with drawRect() with the same result. I have a feeling I'm just not managing my bitmaps well. What I left out of this is that I have 3 other bitmaps allocated with the same 2560x1600 dimension, and I'm going to try and just recycle one of those, or at least gc them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Bitmap.compress() was working as expected. My problem was that I was relying on Samsung's file browsing desktop utility to be updated as the files were written out. This is a no-no. The desktop browsing util was extremely erroneous in this case, and checking the PNG file out with an image viewing app on the device (I used QuickPic and fully endorse it now) showed the real file output.